# How to execute python function in vsc terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

I made python function at vsc and I want to execute that function in terminal like

```
add(2,3)
```

But if so there is an error like bash: syntax error near unexpected token `2,3'
I think the matter of path of terminal but I do not know what to do

I have tried something related to path of terminal but IDK what is matter

Comment: You can open an interactive window with `python3` command, or `python` on Windows. Then do `from filename_where_i_have_add_function import add` and enter. Then on the new line `add(2,3)`

Comment: Why you want to do that? Have you tried jupyter?

Comment: the terminal does **NOT** have Python as scripting language, start a Python REPL

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the file with the function, then run the function through the command line using `python3 -c`

I created a file *sample.py* with your function

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

and I ran the following command from the command-line terminal.

```
python3 -c 'from sample import add; print(add(2,3))'
```

and the output was

```
5
```

Note that, I am using Linux, that's why it is `python3`, for windows, you need to use `python` only.

Comment: it all depends how many Python interpreters you have and how many virtual environments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your function from the command line a lot, it may be cleanest to make it an executable script. On Linux:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3 

from sys import argv


def add(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2])))
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x add.py
```

Now you can run it from the terminal:

```
./add.py 2 3
5
```

If you are going to make it more complex, I recommend checking out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It's more powerful than `argv`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to open the python terminal first

   [image]
2. Define the function

   [image]
3. Then execution function

   [image]

*You can also select part of the code in the script file, and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the python interactive terminal and execute the code.*

You can read [Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) in detail.

In addition, it may be more convenient to use [Jupyter Notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).